# The circuit breaker keeps tripping when I turn my washer on, nothing happens when its turned off

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

When the washing machine is turned on the circuit braker keeps tripping and the washer does not come on.

I tried plugging in the vacuum and it did not trip so what is wrong?

Comment: Try the washer in a different outlet. If that circuit breaker trips then something is wrong with the washer. If the circuit breaker does not trip then something is wrong with the breaker.

Comment: Is this a standard (over-current) breaker or is it a GFCI breaker?

Comment: If the fault is in the washing machine, it is possible that the fault is in the cord. First, unplug the cord and use the resistance setting of a VOM to determine the resistance of the hot to the gnd, hot to neutral, and gnd to neutral. Do this first with the power switch off and then with it on. This might tell you something. If you get a result that indicates a problem, then you might remove the cord and test the cord in isolation and test the machine without the cord connected.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are good the problem is the washer, since the vacuum worked fine in that outlet.  To be certain, plug the washer into another outlet and see if the washer trips the breaker in the new outlet.

You should have the washer checked and serviced.  Since it's showing problems severe enough to trip the circuit breaker it's not a job you should do yourself unless you are competent troubleshooting high voltage electric circuits.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a dangerous fault in your washer and your breaker is doing its job of preventing the washer from burning the house down or killing you in other ways.

Try plugging in a kettle to the same socket/outlet instead of the washer or vacuum. If the breaker does not trip it means the outlet and breaker are OK.

A kettle usually consumes more power than a vacuum cleaner, so it is a tougher test.

as vini_i commented, if you can move the washer to an outlet that is definitely connected to a separate breaker, you can confirm whether the washer is at fault or the breaker.

How much power a circuit can provide depends on the rating of the circuit breaker. Electrical arrangements depend on which part of the world you live in. So for better help, edit your question and insert some details like country, the rating of the circuit breaker, make and model of washing machine (or details from it's rating plate if visible) and/or clear in-focus photos of breaker, outlet/socket etc.